# how to set numbers as x-axis in R

Tags: r, plotly

I want to make a bar chart and try to add these numbers as x-axis, but it dislocates items 10 and '>10':

```
plot_ly(x = c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'>10'),
        y = c(5, 11, 23,14,21,18,20,19,12,31,21),
        name = "dd",
        type = "bar", 
        xaxis = list(title ="tr"), 
        yaxis = list(title = "cc"))
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: 10 and >10 are there. >10 is first bar and 10 is 3rd.

Comment: but 10 and >10 are meant to be the last and second last items not the first and second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying the layout for xaxis worked for me:

```
plot_ly(x = c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'>10'),
        y = c(5, 11, 23,14,21,18,20,19,12,31,21),
        name = "dd",
        type = "bar", 
        xaxis = list(title ="tr"), 
        yaxis = list(title = "cc")) %>%
  layout(title = "Features",
         xaxis = list(type = "category",
                      title = "tr"),
         yaxis = list(title = "cc"))
```

[image: plotly v2]

Comment: Thanks Z.Lin its great just there is no title for the graph and x and y axises

Comment: @BehrouzMahmoudi Have updated my answer. You can add them using the `title = ""` command. See [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/) for reference.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much Z.Lin.

Comment: The "trick" applied by @Z.Lin is to tell Plotly to interpret the x-values as 'catagorical' values (`layout: xaxis: type: categorical`) and not as numbers. This prevents Plotly from sorting the values.

Comment: COULD you also say HOW TO ADD VALUES on the top of each bar ?            I tried "text(x=x, y=y, labels=y)" but didnt work

Comment: try `text = c(5, 11, 23,14,21,18,20,19,12,31,21), textposition = 'auto'`, see https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-direct-labels

Comment: Thanks Maximillian, it worked but adds value in the bar NOT on the top :(

Comment: @BehrouzMahmoudi This is getting well beyond the scope of your original question. You may wish to pose a new one. It'll get more attention there.